# How to make NSWindow appear from button action (Swift 3) (Mac OSX)

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nswindow

I set the NSWindow as "hidden at launch". How do I make NSWindow appear (pop up) when a button is pressed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a reference to the window in your code, then call its `makeKeyAndOrderFront` method. Unless you specifically desire a different behavior, you can pass `nil` as the sender. Note that if you have selected the "Release When Closed" option on the NSWindow in question, this may cause problems when trying to show the window once it has already been opened and subsequently closed once.

Comment: Thank you for the well-detailed answer! This helped me solve my issue!